# SSIS deployment model confused

Tags: deployment, installation, ssis

I am trying to understand SSIS deployment for 2012.

We can store and execute package from :- File system , MSDB  and SQL Server SSIDB.

Some questions

1. When i create a setup using project deployment of 2012 . Can i use the ISPAC file will to deploying to file system and MSDB as i do not see any option for the same.
2. Is File system and MSDB only for back ward compatibility and should be avoided from 2012 onwards.
3. Is ISPAC setup only for deploying to SQL Server SSIDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to 1 & 3, yes the ISPAC setup is only for deploying to SSISDB.

In answer to 2, personally I am leaning away from Project Deployment and SSISDB. My main issue is that when you have multiple developers at varying stages of various changes to various packages, you can get horribly jammed up trying to deploy anything.  VS will only deploy if it can build the entire project, so your change can be blocked by someone elses incomplete work.  It insists on deploying the entire project.

These issues lead developers to postpone checking in their changes for days or weeks, which cant be a good thing.

The SSISDB database also seems a bit "Version 1" and has a few scalability and performance issues.

I prefer MSDB for now, deployed using BIDSHelper.

Comment: Thanks that helped how to mark this as answer i have upvoted will that make it a answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mike Honey: Mind updating the english in the question? (not a grammar enthusiast but sentences have to make sense to everyone). May be i have little idea on MS BI, so i don't understand the literal meaning of the question. But the broken english in the question is not helping. sorry